# Ways to set "Copy to output directory" based on configuration

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, build

I want to set the "Copy to Output Directory" property based on the build configuration. I haven't tested yet, but I think the `Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'"` should work fine. There is a problem though - I have many content files in my project, I will add much more and I don't want to change each file's property manually. I could write a tool that modifies all content entries, but may be there is another way?

EDIT: at the time of writing this post I desired an easier way, but now I think any other way would be good to consider, so any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: It makes little sense to alter this property for the configuration type.  If you wrote code that expects files to be elsewhere when it was built in the Debug configuration then you should remove that code.

Comment: I have a project that heavily relies on its content (content includes images, config files and some python scripts). I wrote a content packing tool that I want to execute it post-build in the Release configuration, and in Debug I want to access the content as it is, so I can dynamically alter config/script files for the testing purposes. There are two IO wrappers - filesystem IO and packed content IO, content loading code uses the wrapper via the interface, wrapper is created in one place, so I can just enclose one line in `#if DEBUG #else #endif` or so.

Comment: If you or anyone else can propose a more adequate way to keep the content unpacked in Debug and packed in Release, I'm interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to take an easy route and copy content via xcopy on post-build and set all "copy to output directory" properties to "do not copy":

```
mkdir $(TargetDir)\Content
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug goto :debug
:release
$(ProjectDir)\Tools\PackTool.exe $(ProjectDir)Content\ $(TargetDir)Content\Content.dat
goto :exit
:debug
xcopy $(ProjectDir)\Content $(TargetDir)\Content /q /s /e /y
:exit
```